# Alternative styles in code for DataGrid rows in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` with its `RowStyle` set in XAML:

```xml
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightSteelBlue"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Aquamarine"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

The `DataGrid` contains rowdetails which I wish to print when that row is selected.  However, I need to change the background colour of the row (including its rowdetails) from Aquamarine to White when printing and then back again after printing. I have the following method to achieve this:

```cs
private void ChangeStyle(bool printing)
{
    Style rsRowStyle = new Style();
    Style oldStyle = dgdCustomersListing.RowStyle;
    Trigger DataTrigger = new Trigger();
    DataTrigger.Property = DataGridRow.IsSelectedProperty;
    DataTrigger.Value = true;
    rsRowStyle.Triggers.Add(DataTrigger);
    Setter TriggerSetter = new Setter();
    TriggerSetter.Property = DataGridRow.BackgroundProperty;
    TriggerSetter.Value = Brushes.LightGray;
    rsRowStyle.Setters.Add(TriggerSetter);
    dgdCustomersListing.RowStyle = printing ? rsRowStyle : oldStyle;
}
```

This works fine when first called for printing (the row background converts to white), but calling the method again when `printing` is `false` fails to revert the `DataGrid` back to the original style.

Why does it not work?

Comment: I think you should define the Background by default  explicitly outside of triggers.

Answer (score 0):

My error: the assignment to `oldStyle` needs to be made when first calling the printing method, and then passing that value to the `ChangeStyle` method so that it is not changed by that method. Hence:

```cs
private void ChangeStyle(bool printing, Style oldStyle)
{
    Style rsRowStyle = new Style();
    Trigger DataTrigger = new Trigger();
    DataTrigger.Property = DataGridRow.IsSelectedProperty;
    DataTrigger.Value = true;
    rsRowStyle.Triggers.Add(DataTrigger);
    Setter TriggerSetter = new Setter();
    TriggerSetter.Property = DataGridRow.BackgroundProperty;
    TriggerSetter.Value = Brushes.LightGray;
    rsRowStyle.Setters.Add(TriggerSetter);
    dgdCustomersListing.RowStyle = printing ? rsRowStyle : oldStyle;
}
```

I have left this up as Q&A as it took me some time to sort out how to change the style in code, and I hope this might be useful to others.